# Regex is allowing characters not specified in the pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to ensure a field on my form contains **only** alphanumeric characters. Zero through Nine, A through Z. No punctuation, no special characters, nothing else.

I have the following method:

```
function foo()
{
    var pStrValue = mTrim($('#txtIDNumber').val());

    var regexFirstChar = new RegExp("^[A-Z0-9]{1}"); //First character is alphanumeric
    var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$"); // First 9 are numeric
    var regexLetter1 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}$"); //Up to the first 3 are alpha, then there are exactly 6 numbers
    var regexLetter2 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{9}$"); //Up to the first 3 are alpha, then there are exactly 9 numbers

    var firstCharIsNum = !isNaN(pStrValue.charAt(0));

    if (!regexFirstChar.test(pStrValue)) //If the first character isn't alphanumeric
        return false;
    else if (firstCharIsNum) 
    {
        //this is the conditional that evaluates to true incorrectly
        if (!regexNum.test(pStrValue)) //If the first character is a number and is not proceeded by 8 more digits
            return false;
    }
    else if (!firstCharIsNum) 
    {
        if (!regexLetter1.test(pStrValue) && !regexLetter2.test(pStrValue)) //If the first 1-3 characters are letters and are not proceed by exactly 6 or 9 digits
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that this is accepting special characters. I entered `1234567890”,’”` into the textbox and this passes validation.

I wrote this a year ago and it was definitely working then (or I suppose perhaps QA missed this), but since then our application has gone under a *significant* rewrite. In either case, regex definitely isn't my strong suit. Why is this allowing special characters?

Comment: You have an unescaped period in your regex.

Comment: @Tushar why do you need a $ when the regex is only to validate the beginning of the string?

Comment: But it would allow non-numeric/non-alpha characters which is the complaint.

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to add a note as to which regex is failing. Updated my post with a new comment in the code, `if (!regexNum.test(pStrValue))` is evaluating undesirably.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Please consider providing a live demo.

Comment: Wait, what is `mTrim` ?

Comment: A [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/5tmqyn7u/) says you have not posted everything.

Comment: @revo Just removes leading and trailing spaces

Comment: If you write "^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$" it accept 9 numbers + whatever character (as u write **.{0, 3}**  and . means everything) so u can write 123456789'è, for example

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is extremely strange. I can assure you I posted the entirety of the code, with the exception of my method actually returning some strings instead of simply `true` or `false`

Comment: See revo's comment, and also google cannot find `mTrim`

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, that's the point of what I said.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. Dave was correct; I didn't escape the period when I should have. `regexNum` has been changed to `"^[0-9]{9}\\.[A-Z0-9]{0,3}$"`. Exactly nine digits, followed by up to 3 alphanumerics only.

Comment: I suspect `mTrim` not only trims leading and trailing spaces but also some more characters including punctuation marks.

Comment: @revo It's 5 lines of code; `while (aStrValue.substring(0, 1) == ' ') aStrValue = aStrValue.substring(1, aStrValue.length);` and then that again except starting from the end of the string instead of the beginning then returns the new value.

Comment: For that purpose JavaScript has a native method `.trim()`. As you saw in the demo that @Wiktor made, it simply fails. In your case something else obviously is in charge of it.

Comment: @revo I didn't write it, I just inherited it :(

Comment: @Joe's solution is only a healer but as the reason is not known yet it may cause problems later. I think you'd better dig deep to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i intend your question `regexNum` tests if the string is made of exactly **9 digits** + **0-3 alphanumeric characters** [0-9A-Z]. If so:

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}[0-9A-Z]{0,3}$"); // First 9 are numeric + 0-3 of any alphanumeric characters, end of string.
```

As you requested this allows no punctuation, no special characters, nothing else, just 0-9 and A-Z.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. It was a mistake to use the `.` a year ago due to poor wording in the requirements doc. On one page, it says "9 numbers + up to 3 characters" then on another page it says "up to 3 alphanumeric characters". Must've missed that last year and used the `.` thinking **any** character was acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, the problem is in your line:

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$");
```

The `.` allows *any* character between zero and three times. At a minimum, you need to escape it as `\.` -- but I think what you're really looking for is (for nine digits before the decimal point, and three digits after):

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}\.[0-9]{0,3}$");
```

Comment: `\\.`. It's a string or use literal syntax.

Comment: `^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$` means 9 digits followed by 3 characters at most. Period. Test input has 14 characters in total! How do they match?

Answer (score 1):

Your regexNum allows (after 9 numbers) up to 3 chars, no matter what:

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$");
```

So you could simply remove this part and it will only allow exactly 9 digits

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}$");
```

Here you may test it:
http://regexr.com/3eaa5

edit: With 3 optional alphanumeric values (upper- or lowercase) after the 9 numbers, it would be:

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}[A-Z0-9]{0,3}$");
```

Comment: You're on the right track; the use of the `.` was incorrect due to some poor requirements doc wording, but it needs to accept up to 3 alphanumerics afterwards, as Davide Vozzi supplied in his solution, whereas with this the `$` would require that to be the end of the value, right?

Comment: yes, `$` indicates the end. I've updated the post to reflect the case with optional 3 alphanumeric values after the 9 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegEx

```
var regularExp = new RegExp("^[0-9]{0,9}.{0,3}$");
```

Explaination:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[0-9]{0,9} match a single character between 0 to 9
$ assert position at end of the string
```